# Martingale conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation, martingales, characteristic-functions

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and let $X$ be such that; $$P(X=(\frac{3}{2})^n) = 2^{-n}.$$

For $n \geq 1$, define $A_n = {\{X = (\frac{3}{2})^n)}\}$, and let $\mathcal{F_n}$ be the sigma field generated by $A_1, ..., A_n$.

Set $Z_n = E(X|\mathcal{F_n})$. It is easy to show this is a martingale with respect to the sigma field above.

Now, for $n \geq 1$ define $B_n = {\{X > (\frac{3}{2})^n)}\}$, then ${\{A_1, A_2, ..., A_n, B_n}\}$ forms a finite partition of $\Omega$ that generates $\mathcal{F_n}$.

I have been asked to show that $$Z_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{3}{2})^k\cdot I_{A_k} + 2(\frac{3}{2})^{n+1}\cdot I_{B_n}$$

Where $I_{A_k}, I_{B_n}$ are indicator functions.

I don't know where to start here. I don't really understand the variable $Z_n$, which is conditioned on the sigma field generated by ${\{A_1, A_2, ..., A_n, B_n}\}$.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The sigma field generated by ${\{A_1, A_2, ..., A_n, B_n}\}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$ since $B_n = (\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i)^{\text{c}}$

Comment: @clark Ok thank you. I don't see how this helps solve the problem, though?

Comment: Since $\cup A_i \cup B_n$ forms partition of the sigma field $\mathcal{F}_n$ is suffices to verify the desired equality for each of the events. To show that for each event you can use $E(X|A)=E(X1_A)/\mathbb{P}(A)$ where $A$ is an event.

Comment: @clark So $Z_n = E(X|A_1) + ...  + E(X|A_n) + E(X|B_n)$?

Comment: Not quite, notice that your RHS, as is, is a number not a random variable, we should write it as $E(X|A_1)1_{A_1}+\ldots$ . More specifically, on the event $A_i$  $Z_n= E(X|F_n)= E(X|A_i)$, which you can compute as mentioned in the above comments.

Comment: @clark How is $E[XI_A]$ worked out?

Comment: By definition of $A_i$ $X=\left ( \frac{3}{2}\right )^n$, therefore the expectation transforms into $\left ( \frac{3}{2}\right )^n E(1_{A_i})=\left ( \frac{3}{2}\right )^n \mathbb{P}(A_i)$. And that probability is given as a hypothesis in the problem

Comment: @clark Thank you very much for your help. Do you know how $E[XI_{B_n}]$ would be worked out?

Comment: Set $B_{n,i}= \left (\frac{3}{2}\right )^{n+i}$ for $i\geq 1$, then notice that $\bigcup_{i\geq 1} B_{n,i} = B_n$ and that $B_{n,i}$ are disjoint. Finally, rewrite $1_{B_n} =\sum_{i\geq 1} 1_{B_{n,i}} $ and compute each $E(X1_{B_{n,i}})$ as before.

Comment: @clark So $E[X|B_{n}] = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} E[X|B_k]?$ Doesn't this yield $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} (\frac{3}{2})^k$?

Comment: Not quite $E(X|B_n)$ is not equal the expression you describe. $E(X|B_n)= E(X1_{B_n})/\mathbb{P}(B_n)$.  After having done that, then you calculate $  E(X1_{B_n})  $ as discussed.

Comment: @clark I don't quite understand the relationship between $E[X|B_n]$ and $E[X|B_{n,i}]$

Comment: @clark By that method I get $$E[XI_B_n] = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} (\frac{3}{2})^k$$

Comment: the calculation was too big to reproduce here, so I posted it as an answer instead. The comments should fill the gaps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\sigma$-algebra on countable set is generated by a partition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791664/sigma-algebra-on-countable-set-is-generated-by-a-partition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find $Z_n$, it suffices to calculate $E(X|A_i)$ and $E(X|B_n)$. We can calculate $E(X|B_n)$, and, the others can be computed similarly. We set $B_{n,i}=\{X=\left (\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n+i}\}$ for $i\geq 1$.

\begin{align}
E(X|B_n) &=  \frac{E(X;B_n)}{\mathbb{P}(B_n)}\\
&=\frac{E(X1_{B_n})}{\mathbb{P}(B_n)}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{i\geq 1}E(X1_{B_{n,i}})}{\mathbb{P}(B_n)}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{i\geq 1}\left ( \frac{3}{2}\right )^{i}E(1_{B_{n,i}})}{\mathbb{P}(B_n)}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{i\geq 1}\left ( \frac{3}{2}\right )^{n+i}2^{-(n+i)}}{\sum_{i\geq 1}2^{-(n+i)}  }\\
&=\frac{\sum_{i\geq 1}\left ( \frac{3}{2}\right )^{n+i}2^{-i}}{\sum_{i\geq 1}2^{-i}  }\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left ( \frac{3}{2}\right )^{n+1}\frac{\sum_{i\geq 0}\left ( \frac{3}{4}\right )^{i}}{\sum_{i\geq 1}2^{-i+1}  }\\
&=2\left ( \frac{3}{2}\right )^{n+1}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: If $T =$ min${\{n \geq 1 : Z_n = X}\}$ is a stopping time, could you possibly give me any hints on how to show that $T = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \cdot I_{A_n}?$ My thoughts are that $X = E[X|\mathcal{F_n}]$, so $X$ is independent of the sigma field, but this isn't getting me anywhere!

Comment: @theman I think it would be easier to address this in a different post. As, there would be the option to give feedback in form of an answer, and others would also be able to contribute as well.