# Sum of two martingales

Tags: probability, summation, expectation, martingales

Let ${\{X_n}\}_{n \geq 0}$ and ${\{Y_n}\}_{n \geq 0}$ be two martingales. How do I show that $$\sum_{k=1}^n E[(X_k - X_{k-1})(Y_k - Y_{k-1})] = E[X_n Y_n] - E[X_0 Y_0]?$$

I tried expanding the terms and writing the first few terms of the sum out but nothing seems to be cancelling.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Since $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ are martingales, for each $k\geq 1$ we have
$$ \mathbb{E}[(X_k-X_{k-1})(Y_k-Y_{k-1})]=\mathbb{E}[X_kY_k]-\mathbb{E}[X_kY_{k-1}]-\mathbb{E}[X_{k-1}Y_k]+\mathbb{E}[X_{k-1}Y_{k-1}]$$
$$ =\mathbb{E}[X_kY_k]-\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_kY_{k-1}\mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1}]]-\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{k-1}Y_{k}\mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1}]]+\mathbb{E}[X_{k-1}Y_{k-1}]$$
$$=\mathbb{E}[X_kY_k]-\mathbb{E}[Y_{k-1}\mathbb{E}[X_k\mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1}]]-\mathbb{E}[X_{k-1}\mathbb{E}[Y_{k}\mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1}]]+\mathbb{E}[X_{k-1}Y_{k-1}]$$
$$=\mathbb{E}[X_kY_k]-\mathbb{E}[X_{k-1}Y_{k-1}]$$
and hence the sum telescopes.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you mind checking out another question of mine that I can't seem to solve?; https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2606433/285167. Any help would be much appreciated!