# Prove that smallest $\sigma$-algebra on a partition is $\left\{\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i : I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}\right\}$

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am stuck with this problem. I want to prove this equality but I don't know how to do it. First of all I am going to define what is a $\sigma$-algebra is:

Let $X$ be a set. Then a sigma-algebra $F$ is a nonempty collection of subsets of $X$ such that the following hold:

1. $X$ is in $F$.
2. If $A$ is in $F$, then so is $(X\setminus A)$.
3. If $A_n$ is a sequence of elements of $F$, then the union of the $A_n$ is in $F$.

If $S$ is any collection of subsets of $X$, then we can always find a sigma-algebra containing $S$, namely the power set of $X$. By taking the intersection of all sigma-algebras containing $S$, we obtain the smallest such sigma-algebra. We call the smallest sigma-algebra containing $S$ the sigma-algebra generated by $S$.

Being $\Omega$ a set and $\{A_1, A_2,...,A_n\}$ a partition of it. I have to prove that:

$$\sigma (\{A_1, A_2,...,A_n\})=\left\{\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i : I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}\right\}$$

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to show $\sigma\{A_1, \ldots, A_n\} = \left\{\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i : I \subset \{1, \ldots, n\}\right\}$.

To prove the inclusion $\subseteq$, just show the right-hand side is a $\sigma$-algebra.

To prove the inclusion $\supseteq$, show that any $\sigma$-algebra that contains the left-hand side must also contain the right-hand side.

---

Edit to clarify my last sentence:

I should have written "any $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\{A_1, \ldots, A_n\}$ must also contain the right-hand side."

First show that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\{A_1, \ldots, A_n\}$, then $\mathcal{F}$ must contain $\{\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i : I \subset \{1, \ldots, n\}\}$.

Then note that the intersection of all such $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{F}$ containing $\{A_1, \ldots, A_n\}$ must also contain $\{\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i : I \subset \{1, \ldots, n\}\}$.

Finally, note that $\sigma\{A_1, \ldots, A_n\}$ is the intersection of all such $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I have a doubt, why I have to prove that is equal to the union if I have a sum?

Comment: @Negreanu The sum notation should be union. It is either a typo or it is meant to denote union.

Comment: About the LHS$/subset$ RHS, why need to show any $\sigma$ Algebra contains the LHS must contain the RHS? Why does work?

Comment: Why "show that any σ-algebra that contains the left-hand side must also contain the right-hand side." work?

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui For a collection $\mathcal{S}$ of sets, the notation $\sigma(\mathcal{S})$ denotes the intersection of all sigma-algebras that contain the sets in $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused about that. In your proof, for any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$, I can prove that if $\sigma\{A_{i}\}\subset \mathcal{F}$, then $\{\cup_{i} A_{i}\}\subset \mathcal{F}$. But why this could imply that   $\{\cup_{i} A_{i}\}\subset \sigma\{A_{i}\}$?

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui See my edit.

Comment: Hi, I'm not the OP but I have a question: how do I show that the RHS is a sigma algebra? I know how to do step 2, but I'm just not sure how I can prove step 1. Could you provide an explanation or point me to a resource which has a proof? Thanks.

Comment: @D.R. Just check that it satisfies the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra, e.g. the three conditions mentioned in OP's question.