# How to find a typical element of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a partition of $X$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

We can get a sigma-algebra $\sigma(A_1, A_2,..., A_n)$ which is generated by the partition $A_1, A_2,..., A_n$ of the space $X$ and $A_i$'s are disjoint and their union is $X$.

> My question is what is a typical element of the $\sigma(A_1, A_2,..., A_n)$?

I think it is the all finite union of the $A_1, A_2,..., A_n$, but I am not sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that smallest $\sigma$-algebra on a partition is $\left\{\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i : I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}\right\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791664/prove-that-smallest-sigma-algebra-on-a-partition-is-left-bigcup-i-in-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\mathcal C$ denote your partition, and $\Sigma$ be the collection of all finite unions of sets in your partition, along with the empty set. Show that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and conclude that $\sigma(\mathcal C) \subseteq \Sigma$. Then argue that $\Sigma \subseteq \sigma (\mathcal C)$.

Comment: Since $P_{i} \in \Sigma$, it is clear that $\sigma(\mathcal{C})\subset \Sigma$. Could you tell me how to show$\Sigma\subset \sigma(\mathcal{C})$?

Comment: It is not true that $\Sigma \subset \mathcal C$. However, it is true that each finite union of sets in $\mathcal C$ is in $\sigma(\mathcal C)$. This is enough to show that $\Sigma \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal C)$.

Comment: I think it is easy to show that for every $P_{i}\in \sigma(\mathcal{C})$, we have $\cup_{i} P_{i} \in \Sigma$. So $\sigma(\mathcal{C}) \subset \Sigma$. But how about the reverse? thanks.

Comment: @LoveGQY Sorry, I missed your reply. I sketched how to show the reverse in my previous comment. Is this still giving you difficulty?

Comment: @ Oh, thanks a lot. I have understood it.