# Counting the number of elements in a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given the set  $\Omega = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$, I would like to find the number of elements in the $\sigma$-algebra given by the partitions $A_1$ = {1,2,3,4,5} and $A_2$ = {7,8}.

My approach so far has been to calculate all the possible elements in the  $\sigma$-algebra using the complementary and union axioms from the definition. But is there an easier way to obtain this number?

Comment: Yes... just recognize that there are three "atoms", namely being $A_1,A_2$ and the remaining set $A_3$ consisting of the rest of the elements... specifically $A_3=\{6,9,10\}$.  Every set is built using these three building blocks.  Compare the set of possible sets you can construct in your algebra to the powerset $\mathcal{P}(\{1,2,3\})$.  You should know how many elements exist in a powerset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that smallest $\sigma$-algebra on a partition is $\left\{\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i : I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}\right\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791664/prove-that-smallest-sigma-algebra-on-a-partition-is-left-bigcup-i-in-i) (it is equivalent to @JMoravitz 's comment, and I agree with him that it should suffice).